# Load File to Array

Tags: vb.net

I'm tired of searching about Load file from pc to my app. and then read a file in hex. 
Now I have these code and everything is ok with small file size. Less than 1GB files

**my question is**

all of us know Hex files reader like (*Hex Workshop Editor 6... and Hex Editor Neo*)

I download these and I read the hex of file over (36 GB) (39,490,420,735 bytes)
**without any save bytes in Ram Memory**???

IN vb.Net when I try to read Hex of file over 1GB in array.> windows 7 not responding

I know that's because I have 2GB in my machine!

***what's the way that (hex workshop) use to load any file Regardless of size***

This is the code that I use.

```
X = String.Join(" ", IO.File.ReadAllBytes("Location of file").Select(Function(b) b.ToString("X2")).ToArray())
```

Please any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those programs use a form of [Paging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging)

Basically, they only read in part of the file at a time, they remember the place where they last read, then when the user scrolls they fetch another "page" of data from the file.

.Net 4.0 includes direct support for [Memory Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) which may help, but even without that API this is straight forward to do.

e.g. Simple (untested) paging class.

```
Public Class PagedFile
    Implements IDisposable

    Private stream As IO.BinaryReader
    Private pageSize As Integer
    Public Sub New(fileName As String, pageSize As Integer)
        stream = New IO.BinaryReader(New IO.FileStream(fileName, IO.FileMode.Open))
        Me.pageSize = pageSize
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property PageCount As Integer
        Get
            Dim pages As Double = stream.BaseStream.Length / pageSize
            If stream.BaseStream.Length Mod pageSize = 0 Then
                Return CInt(pages)
            Else
                Return CInt(Math.Floor(pages)) + 1
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

    ' 0 is the first page
    Public Function GetPage(pageNo As Integer) As Byte()
        If (pageNo < 0) Then
            Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("pageNo", "Must be greater than zero")
        End If
        If (pageNo >= PageCount) Then
            Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("pageNo", "Must be less than the number of pages in this file: " & PageCount)
        End If
        stream.BaseStream.Seek(pageNo * pageSize, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
        Return stream.ReadBytes(pageSize)
    End Function

#Region "IDisposable Support"
End Class
```

Hope this helps.

**Update**
Sorry, but I don't understand what you're asking for in your comment.
In your UI you just need to remember which page you're on, and fetch the next page as the user scrolls (or keep 3 pages loaded at any one time, the previous, current and next pages), as the users pages down you have the next page to show immediately, and can fetch another (the new next page) ASynchronously, or when the UI is idle.

**NB** It may make sense to have a "page" be larger than what the user sees, so that the user isn't waiting every time they hit the `Page Down` key.